# Segmentation fault with my fgets?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

it seems my program has something causing a fault, and it gets stuck right after trying to invoke fgets. i could be wrong, but thats where it seems to stop, so anyone know what the issue is?

the file has my header, which contains the definitions and structs, and is mainly used to sort through a completed list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include"compare.h"
#define BLOCK 2

int input_record(record *rec, record_list *list);
void list_init(record_list *list);
void list_destroy(record_list *list);
void list_print(record_list *list);
int check_args(const char arg1[], const char arg2[], record_list *list);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
record_list list;
record rec;
char arg1[3];
char arg2[3];

/*check for proper number of arguments*/
if(argc > 3 || argc < 1){
    return 0;
}
/*run default if no switches*/
if(argc == 1){
    input_record(&rec, &list);
} else {

    strcpy(arg1, argv[1]);
    strcpy(arg2, argv[2]);
    arg1[3] = '\0';
    arg2[3] = '\0';

    input_record(&rec, &list);
    if(check_args(arg1, arg2, &list) == 0){
        printf("error");
    }
}

list_print(&list);
list_destroy(&list);

return 0;
}

int input_record(record *rec, record_list *list){
    int score;
    int min = -1;
    int max = 101;
    int count = 0;
    char first_name[NAMESIZE];
    char last_name[NAMESIZE];
    char temp[LINESIZE];
    record *nrec;

    list_init(list);

    for(count = 0; count < NLINES; count++){
        printf("Enter first name, last name, score\n");
/* !! seg fault occurs once i enter the data !! */
        if(fgets(temp, LINESIZE, stdin) == 0){
            break;
        }
        printf("222222");
        if(sscanf(temp, "%s %s %d", first_name, last_name, &score) == 3){
            if(strlen(first_name) >= NAMESIZE || strlen(last_name) >= NAMESIZE){
                printf("error");
                continue;
            }              
            if(score < min || score > max){
                printf("error");
                continue;
            }
        }

record *tempRec;

        if(list->nalloc == 0){
            tempRec = malloc(sizeof(record));
            if(tempRec == 0){
                return 0;
            }
            #ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "#\n");
            #endif
            list->nalloc = 1;
            list->data = tempRec;

            }else if(list->nalloc == list->nused){
                tempRec = realloc(list->data, (list->nalloc*BLOCK) * sizeof(record));
                if(tempRec == 0){
                    return 0;
                }
            list->data = tempRec;
            list->nalloc *= BLOCK;  
        }

        list->data[list->nused] = *rec;
        strcpy(rec->name.first, first_name);
        strcpy(rec->name.last, last_name);
        rec->score = score;
        list->nused++;    
    }
return 1;
}

void list_init(record_list *list){
list->nused = 0;
list->nalloc = 0;
list->data = 0;
}

void list_destroy(record_list *list){
free(list->data);
list->nalloc = 0;
list->nused = 0;
}

void list_print(record_list *list){
int count;
int listsize = sizeof(list);

for (count = 0; count < listsize; count++){
    printf("%s %s %d", list->data[count].name.last, list->data[count].name.first, list->data[count].score);
}
}

int check_args(const char arg1[], const char arg2[], record_list *list){
char nameDown[] = "-n";
char nameUp[] = "+n";
char scoreDown[] = "-s";
char scoreUp[] = "+s";

/*if either argument is not one of the valid switches, kill function*/
if((strcmp(arg1, nameDown) != 0) || (strcmp(arg1, nameUp) != 0) || (strcmp(arg1, scoreDown) != 0) || (strcmp(arg1, scoreUp) != 0)){
    return 0;
}

if((strcmp(arg2, nameDown) != 0) || (strcmp(arg2, nameUp) != 0) || (strcmp(arg2, scoreDown) != 0) || (strcmp(arg2, scoreUp) != 0)){
    return 0;
}

/*if the arguments are the same, kill function*/
if (strcmp(arg1, arg2) == 0){
        return 0;
/*otherwise look for all combinations of valid switches*/
} else if (strcmp(arg1, nameDown) == 0){
    if (strcmp(arg2, scoreDown) == 0){
        sort_desc_name_desc_score(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, scoreUp) == 0){
        sort_desc_name_asc_score(list->data);
    /*if same lettered switches are detected, kill function*/
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, nameUp) == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        /*the ps and qs are supposed to be records to be sorted*/
        sort_desc_name(list->data);
    }
} else if (strcmp(arg1, nameUp) == 0){
    if (strcmp(arg2, scoreDown) == 0){
        sort_asc_name_desc_score(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, scoreUp) == 0){
        sort_asc_name_asc_score(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, nameDown) == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        sort_asc_name(list->data);
    }

} else if (strcmp(arg1, scoreDown) == 0){
    if (strcmp(arg2, nameDown) == 0){
        sort_desc_score_desc_name(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, nameUp) == 0){
        sort_desc_score_asc_name(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, scoreUp) == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        sort_desc_score(list->data);
    }

} else if (strcmp(arg1, scoreUp) == 0){
    if (strcmp(arg2, nameDown) == 0){
        sort_asc_score_desc_name(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, nameUp) == 0){
        sort_asc_score_asc_name(list->data);
    } else if (strcmp(arg2, scoreDown) == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        sort_asc_score(list->data);
    }
/*and in case anything else got through*/
} else {
    return 0;
}

return 1;
}
```

thats the whole program, seg fault occurs in the input_record function. any cuz of this i have yet to be able to test my code for the other functions yet ...

Comment: What line does the segfault occur on? Attach a debugger and find out.

Comment: it asks for the user input, but doesnt get to the 2's i inserted in there

Comment: LINESIZE is not defined to you...

Comment: `arg1[3] = '\0'; arg2[3] = '\0';` is an off-by-one overflow

Comment: LINESIZE is in my header file with the structs as well

Comment: `if(sscanf(temp, "%s %s %d", first_name, last_name, &score) == 3){}` is dangerous if NAMESIZE < LINESIZE. Better parse manually, scanning for space in the line. `if(fgets(temp, LINESIZE, stdin) == 0){
}` comparing pointers to ints is not a good habit.

Comment: @RejectionHurts - That doens't really tell you anything, if the first `fgets` succeeds, then you will `break` out of the loop, skipping the 2s.

Comment: i originally had it as (!fegts(...)), and that was faulting too.

Comment: My standard way is to loop with `while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp)) {}` Your outer loop (what is NLINES, a retry count?) is mostly ascaped from by breaks or early returns. BTW: the function is too large, IMHO. split it up; that will at least keep al these allocations located in one place.

Comment: NLINES is the maximum number of lines to read

Comment: nice, tried your loop wildplasser and no more fault, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've called `realloc()` on `nrec`, but you've never `malloc`'d or `calloc`'d anything to it.

```
nrec = realloc(list->data, (list->nalloc + 1) * sizeof(record));
```

You have a reference to `list`, but you have no memory associated with it either. Hence, the segfault once you attempt to access it via `realloc()`.

You should never be directly storing the results of any memory allocation to a reference, due to a possible memory leak, if it doesn't allocate anything. A safer solution is, as follows:

```
temp = malloc(SIZE OF DATA);
if(temp == NULL)
{
    priontf("Malloc returned null!\n");
    return -1;
}
nrec = temp;
```